# Managing (and pinning) package versions with puppet

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, apt

I have an installation that I'm trying to manage with puppet.  For some of the packages we want to have very tight control over the versions.  Since they are critical to our application, we only upgrade them after testing in our test environment, and we schedule upgrades during low traffic times.  I don't want puppet to upgrade my database whenever a new package appears. I specified the version in my puppet manifest to prevent the package from automatically upgrading, however when I went to generate another instance using the same config, that version of the package was gone from the Ubuntu repo.  Only the more recent ones are there.

For some of the packages, I've been packing them myself into my own repo, however packaging the database (postgresql) has proven too be too much overhead.

Any solutions or ideas?

We're using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Comment: This question is specific to puppet but not apt or ubuntu.  The basics apply to both apt and yum managed package installations.

Answer (score 2):

This is not Puppet problem but a problem of how you manage your package repositories.

If you absolutely need to stick to a specific version of a package then you must not rely on any second or third party to keep providing it for you. At the very least you need to keep it in a repository controlled by you, as you are doing. And rolling your own packages cannot be "too much overhead" if they are so mission-critical to you, so that argument doesn't count.

You should look into mirroring the upstream repositories (apt-mirror, rsync) and decide yourself when to expire packages. That way you always have the versions you need at hand.

Regarding PostgreSQL I can tell you that the Ubuntu and Debian packages can be upgraded easily and safely; there's no need to stick to a specific (old) version of the package for fear of breaking something. Just make sure you control the time and place of package upgrades and subsequent service restarts, but that goes without saying.

Comment: Thanks, I should probably look into mirroring the upstream repos.  Is there a way to mirror a set of packages (and their dependencies) ? I looked at apt-mirror, and it seems it would delete packages no longer available in the upstream repo.

Comment: Use wget or rsync with the right options.